# Android - ListView item click show data to new activity

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a listview that is populated with sqlite data. I want to show the detailed data on new activity once the listview item is click. My codes below makes the app crash when the listview item is click. Please see my codes.

Listview item click codes

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            Cursor res = myDB.getPersonnelList();
            Intent intent = new Intent(User.this, PersonnelDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", res.getInt(0));
            intent.putExtra("barcode", res.getString(1));
            intent.putExtra("name", res.getString(2));
            intent.putExtra("position", res.getString(3));
            intent.putExtra("number", res.getString(4));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

DatabaseHelper getList

```
public Cursor getPersonnelList(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " +TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}
```

Detailed activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_personnel_details);

    editBar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_bar);
    editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_neym);
    editPos = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pos);
    editNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_num);
    //imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_pic);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null){
        s_id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        s_bar = intent.getStringExtra("barcode");
        s_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        s_pos = intent.getStringExtra("position");
        s_num = intent.getStringExtra("number");
    }
    editBar.setText(s_bar);
    editName.setText(s_name);
    editPos.setText(s_pos);
    editNum.setText(s_num);
}
```

Error

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 23
                                                 at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
                                                 at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                                                 at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
                                                 at com.example.chris.monitoring.User$1.onItemClick(User.java:65)
                                                 at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add the error logs

Comment: `Cursor res = myDB.getPersonnelList();  res.moveToFirst();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, cursor need move to expect index to get right value:

```
        Cursor res = myDB.getPersonnelList();
        //res.moveToFirst();
        res.moveToPosition(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(User.this, PersonnelDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", res.getInt(0));
        intent.putExtra("barcode", res.getString(1));
        intent.putExtra("name", res.getString(2));
        intent.putExtra("position", res.getString(3));
        intent.putExtra("number", res.getString(4));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: the app doesn't crash anymore but when i click the other items it still display the first data.

Comment: If want get true data, use need move cursor to right position, examples:
`res.moveToPosition()`

Comment: Show me Adapter of listview

Comment: Note if there is filtering within the adapter position may not correlate with the respective row in the Cursor with this solution.

Comment: Best solution is put data by `id` or `position` if it is unique.

Answer (score 1):

The likely reason for the crash is that you are not moving to a row within the Cursor (**res**) before trying to extract data e.g. `res.getInt(0)`.

However, you need to know where to move the Cursor to. This is hard to say as it's not obvious what the source of the **adapter** is.

If the source of the adapter is a Cursor and hence it's a Cursor Adapter you'd not even need to get the Cursor as the source Cursor would be available and should be positioned accordingly. (see note re about what to send via intent as **l** (as per 4th parameter) would be the **id**).

If the source is an Array then the 3rd parameter **position** should be used to get the respective data from the source array which could contain either the relevant data for the intent (see note re about what to send via intent).

---

#### Note - re what to/could be send via intent.

If you have the **id** of the row, this is all you need to send. The invoked Activity could then retrieve the data according to that **id**.

---

#### Further Assistance

If you want a more precise answer then you'd have to include how the source of the ListView is created. How it is passed to the adapter would also be of use.